# Is the determinant of the difference of matrices equal to the difference of the determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

i.e. does det(A-B) = det(A) - det(B)?
Both A and B are square matrices of the same size.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Your questions will be better perceived if you present your personal efforts towards an answer, alongside the question. There's also a tour and guidelines for writing good questions, in case you're interested. The answer to your question is no, this does not hold. Notice that you can write $A-B=A+(-B)$, and a discussion of the sum can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sum)

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$.

---

An example with nonzero determinants $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: forgot to say, should assume that all determinants exist. det(A) and det(B) do not exist

Comment: @anon They don't exist?

Comment: sorry, for the question yes they do exist. but in this answer they don't.